# Is there any blog plugin which I can use with my existing rails3 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins

I need to add a blog to my existing rails application. I am looking for a such blog-plugin which also give me ability of tagging blogs with seo friendly URLs. Is there any such kind of plugin/gem available compatible with rails3?

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/q/5005167/922954 ? it offers a few decent options.

Comment: blogkit sounds good, never used it myself though. Worth a try I would say

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would STRONGLY encourage you to roll your own.  A blog helps you setup most basic rails concepts. The logic is very easy to write, and you can use external sources to make most of it easier.

Instead of looking for an out of the box solution to solve all of your problems, consider rolling your own and using gems/services where you see fit. I will list some of the common options for a project like this below:

1. [Active Admin](http://activeadmin.info) - for content management / administration (GEM)
2. [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) - for tagging your posts (GEM)
3. [disqus](http://disqus.com) - for comments (SERVICE)
4. [addthis](http://addthis.com) - for sharing (SERVICE)
5. [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki) - for paging your resource (/posts/) (GEM)
6. [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) - slugging your urls (pretty urls) (GEM)
7. [redcarpet](https://github.com/tanoku/redcarpet) - parsing markdown (GEM)

As you can see, most of these would be very useful for rolling your own blog. I wouldn't encourage an out-of-the-box solution for this.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

RefineryCMS is pretty straightforward to drop into an existing rails 3 app following the instructions here: http://refinerycms.com/guides/attaching-refinery-cms-to-an-existing-rails-application - The easiest option I've found for adding a full blog setup to an existing project and SEO and tagging support out of the box.

Comment: Thanks... M gonna try it out just now... :-)